# Change in builtin objects of JavaScript IntelliSense inside VSCode does not show

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I add a function to the `Math` object, it does not show inside IntelliSense of VSCode.

```js
Math.dot = function (a,b) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one already, create a type declaration module file (Ex. `index.d.ts`) in the root of your project folder, and add to it the following:

```
declare interface Math {
   doc: (a:number, b:number) => number;
}
```

You can read more about type declaration module files in the official docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html.

In simpler cases, you can just use [JSDoc comments](https://jsdoc.app/index.html), since [a basic subset of JSDoc comments are supported by VS Code's intelliSense facilities](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking). As far as I know, this is not one of those supported cases (declaring the type of a function on an existing global object).